# Connecting to Remote Desktop Gateway (RDG) server using external static iP address

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, gateway, windows-server-2016, remote-connection

I have two servers: RDG (Remote Desktop Gateway) and Terminal. I want to connect from Internet to Terminal via RDG using external static IP address. The manuals describe cases with domain names only, but I have no domain in my LAN. On my router, I forwarded the port 4430 and redirected it to the RDG-server.
Then I trying to connect to server using RDP-client like so:

```
55.66.77.88:4430
```

I previously configured the RDG-server parameters in my RDP-client (i.e. I entered it hostname). But the connection fails.

[RDG settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDzwY.jpg)

How can I connect?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to connect to the Terminal server through RDGW, and there is no domain name (FQDN), you will need to know the IP addresses of the Terminal server and RDGW.

On the General tab of mstsc, you should input the Terminal server's IP address.
[Computer Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHX70.png)

And then on the Advanced tab, you should specify the IP address of the gateway.
[Server Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjNfh.png)

Comment: If I have forwarded 4430 port on my router (with external ip 55.66.77.88) to RDG-server (192.168.0.10) and my Terminal server has address 192.168.0.150, then should I use this settings?
General tab of mstsc: 192.168.0.150.Terminal;
Advanced tab of mstsc: 55.66.77.88.RDG.

But in theory I should specify the port? Such as
55.66.77.88:4430.RDG (but the mstsc does not accept this name).

And in 1-st case (if I don't specify the port) I get the error:
"The gateway server address is unreachable or incorrect. Enter a correct server address"